# Trying to scrape wikitravel

Tags: xml, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wiki-markup

I am trying to scrape wiki travel for specific data. like climate, getin etc.
I have managed to get the xml from them with special export.

http://wikitravel.org/en/Special:Export/San_Francisco
I got the data in xml form but it is in wiki markup and I tried browsing for a solution to get that text, but was unable to find a suitable solution.

I tried writing a php function with regular expressions so i can convert it into html, but it gets converted in a non uniform manner so very difficult to select specific data.

Also tried writing mediawiki url so I can program something
http://wikitravel.org/en/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content
But it does not work.

Can you please help me with this. Has anyone successfully scraped wikipedia. I there a tutorial or any other technique I can refer.

Comment: I don't understand. How would getting the HTML of the page help you?

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question here: [Where can I find a good MediaWiki Markup parser in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029012/where-can-i-find-a-good-mediawiki-markup-parser-in-php)

I also found this:  https://github.com/codeholic/w/blob/master/creole.php
Which came from: http://www.ivan.fomichev.name/2010/02/php-creole-10-wiki-markup-parser.html

This sounds like a frustrating endeavour, I wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wikitravel's MediaWiki API is at http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php, so try this instead:

http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

You will want to use an API client, see http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code for a selection.  Also beware that Wikitravel uses a *very* old version of MediaWiki (1.11), so many operations in the modern API do not work.