# Wikipedia links regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, unicode, wikipedia

How can I draw only the words in [[words]] into array?

> [[旭川市|旭川]]（文化） - [[アイヌ]]文化、[[旭川市旭山動物園|旭山動物園]]など

I tried `\[\[.*]]` but it didn't work, maybe it is because `.*` is only for English strings..

Comment: Make sure you are loading your text files in the same character encoding they were saved in. If it was saved in Shift-JIS and you try to load it as UTF-8, the string will be effectively unparsable.

Comment: Have you tried using a [MediaWiki parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324758/open-source-parser-code-for-mediawiki-markup) instead of a Regular Expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/u',$str,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: yes, `/u` flag is definitely helpful, though I didn't try this example to make sure it works ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to backslash both sides, all the square brackets need to be escaped.

This worked in Python, may need modification for PHP:

```
>>> re.compile('\[\[(.*?)\]\]')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xb747ebf0>
>>> r=_
>>> r.search(text)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7469560>
>>> r.findall(text)
['\xe6\x97\xad\xe5\xb7\x9d\xe5\xb8\x82|\xe6\x97\xad\xe5\xb7\x9d', '\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x8c', '\xe6\x97\xad\xe5\xb7\x9d\xe5\xb8\x82\xe6\x97\xad\xe5\xb1\xb1\xe5\x8b\x95\xe7\x89\xa9\xe5\x9c\x92|\xe6\x97\xad\xe5\xb1\xb1\xe5\x8b\x95\xe7\x89\xa9\xe5\x9c\x92']
```

Hmm, maybe I'm wrong about having to escape the right-square brackets, turned out it wasn't necessary in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the Unicode first:

```
[&#26093;&#24029;&#24066;&#26093;&#23665;&#21205;&#29289;&#22290;&#124;&#26093;&#23665;&#21205;&#29289;&#22290;&#93;&#93;&#12394;&#12393l]
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're using the **greedy** wildcard: `\[\[.*]]` will match from the first `[[` to the last `]]`, including any intervening `]]`.

Most regex engines now also include a **nongreedy** wildcard, typically `*?` so `\[\[.*?]]` would just match one wikilink at a time.